# Why do string indices (albeit representing integers) work in arrays?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following enumerate correctly?

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = 'foo';
arr['1'] = 'bar';

arr.forEach(v => console.log(v)); // foo, bar
```

Both `arr[1]` and `arr['1']` also work. Is this a feature of `Array` that strings corresponding to integers are mapped to their integer value?

Comment: javascript likes type coercion :p why does `'2' * '5'` work like `2 * 5` :p

Comment: An array in JS can only have integer as  key else is an object

Comment: There's a lot of detail in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript though it may be directly answer the question.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'll accept that as an answer...

Comment: @BenAston Oh. I wasn't answering, I thought it'd be useful to have a link to the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the fact that arrays in Javascript are just objects with some dedicated syntactic sugar.

Compare:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = 'foo';
arr['1'] = 'bar';
console.log(arr['0']);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

... to:

```
var obj = {};
obj[0] = 'foo';
obj['1'] = 'bar';
console.log(obj['0']);
console.log(obj[1]);
```

Basically, `Array` is a type of `Object`, with array specific methods and non-enumerable properties, such as `length`, which can be instantiated with the dedicated shorthand syntax `[ items... ]`

The indices of an array are actually strings, just like all keys in any object, it works because referencing an object property using a number as a key will coerce that number into its string representation (in principle, that is. I assume most modern browsers have internally optimized this heavily).

Example:

```
var obj = {};
obj[1.5] = 'foo';
console.log('1.5' in obj);
console.log(obj[1.5]);

var arr = [];
arr[0.5] = 'foo';
console.log('0.5' in arr);
console.log(arr[0.5]);

arr[0] = 'bar';
arr[1] = 'baz';
console.log(arr.length);
console.log(Object.keys(arr));
```

Comment: @BenAston Maybe it was poorly phrased, but they are properties of the object and the keys of objects are always strings. However, it's *considered* to be an array index only if it is the string representation of a positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

For those questions, It may be worth taking a look into the specification

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. **A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 2^(32)−1**

Thus, because:

```
parseInt("1").toString() === "1"
```

"1" is a perfectly valid array index.

See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4

**EDIT**: One might ask "What's with 1 (a number)", because `parseInt(1).toString()` is not equal to 1 (but "1", a string). I think the answer to this is the part "(in the form of a String value)", so I believe 1 is first interpreted as "1" before applying those rules.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a feature of Array that strings corresponding to integers are
>   mapped to their integer value?

No. Think of Arrays just like regular objects.

When accessing a property of an object using **bracket notation** - the property must be quoted.

eg: `var someVar = { a:1, b:2 }` - to access the value of property 'a' with bracket notation we write: `someVar['a']`

So it makes perfect sense to access array elements via quoted indexes.

That being said, it **isn't necessary** to quote the index - and that's because - as others have mentioned - the index is coerced into a string by the JavaScript engine through an implicit toString conversion

Comment: Thanks. I had it the wrong way around in my head - I thought arrays had integer indices. Instead they have *string* properties that correspond to the  32-bit integer subset of IEEE-754, exposed via the usual indexer (property access) syntax.

Comment: "The way that Arrays differ from objects here is that quoting the index is not necessary " - Are you sure normal objects don't also have this behavior? `var o = {}; o[1] = 'foo'; o[1]; // foo`